# What is the maximum value of the $4 \times 4$ determinant composed of 1-16?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, determinant, discrete-optimization

If 1-9 is filled in the  $3 \times 3$ determinant, and each number appears once,then the maximum value of the determinant is $412$.

For example, the following determinant can take the maximum value of $412$:
$$\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 4 & 8 \\
 7 & 2 & 6 \\
 5 & 9 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right|=412.$$

Question: if 1-16 is filled in the $4\times4$ determinant, and each number appears once, what is the maximum value of the determinant? Is it necessarily less than $16 \times 15 \times 14 \times 13= 43680$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest known value is
$$\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
 12 & 13 & 6 &2 \\
 3 & 8 & 16 &7\\
 14 & 1 & 9 &10 \\
5 &  11   &4   &15
\end{array}
\right|=40800.$$

See this [paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/064_09_JIPAM/064_09_www.pdf) and the OEIS sequence [A085000](https://oeis.org/A085000) as a reference.